# Closing span tags in content editable div

Tags: css, html

I'm creating a content editable div where I certain words I type turn bold and red (using jQuery...etc). I've achieved this by replacing the target words with the same word enclosed by appropriately styled span tags. For example:

```
Target ----> <span style="color:red; font-weight:bold">target</span>
```

The problem is that once I replace the target word with it's spanned version, everything else I type in the content-editable div is placed inside the target word's span tags instead of outside them. So for example:

```
* What I want: <span style="color:red; font-weight:bold">target</span> other words
* What happens: <span style="color:red; font-weight:bold">target other words</span>
```

What's an elegant way around this? I'm trying to avoid adding an extra span that houses a zero-width character and returns the style to normal.

Answer (score 0):

#fill_me {
    font-weight: bold;
    color: red;
}

<span id="fill_me">target</span>

$(' other words').insertAfter('#fill_me');

Comment: I understand the logic, but I'm confused as to how to implement this as the user is directly typing into the content-editable div.

Comment: why would the user be able to do such a thing?

Comment: I'm using a content-editable div like a textarea in this context. The user types into the content-editable div and when he/she types a target word, that word is immediately replaced with red, and bold version of the same word (via span)

Comment: With jquery you can detect a target word with an ajax request by an event triggered such as onChange. the ajax request would simply return a true or false in which case you would replace the target word surrounded with respective span tags. is this not a plausible solution?